# How to calculate the sum for lists of integers in a list using map and get a new list where each entry corresponds to each calculated sum?

Tags: java

I have a `List<List<Integer>>` and need to calculate the sum for each list within the list and store those in a new list, so that said new list has several entries where each corresponds to the previously calculated sums.

This is what I have gotten so far, unfortunately, it does not compile and I am afraid I do not know enough about Java 8 operators yet to solve this on my own.

```
List<Integer> sums = lists.map(return new Function<List<Integer>, 
Integer>(){
    @Override
    public Integer call(List<Integer> list){
        int sum = list.stream().reduce(0, (x,y) -> x+y);
        return new Integer(sum);
    }
});
```

Comment: What does a "list within the list" mean?

Comment: A list of lists of Integers. I need the sum over each of those lists and then a new list with the sums as entries.

Comment: Ah, okay. ernest_k has fixed your formatting; be sure to use the Preview feature.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It wasn't visible in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you mean :

```
List<Integer> sums = lists.stream()
        .map(l -> l.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

I would propose:

```
List<Integer> sumList = list.stream().map(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but one of below will match...
No need to use `reduce()`, java `stream()` has `mapToInt()` and `sum()` instead.

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
List<List<Integer>> intsLists = Arrays.asList(ints, ints, ints);

// get the sum of a single list
Integer sumSingleList = ints.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
// sum multiple lists within a list, get a result per list
List<Integer> sumsMultiList = intsLists.stream().map(e -> e.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()).collect(Collectors.toList());
// sum all lists, get a single total
Integer sumTotalMultiList = intsLists.stream().map(e -> e.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```